# How to fill NAs by factors in data frame, by ID

Tags: r, dataframe, conditional-statements, missing-data

I have a data frame with a column ID (there are more than 800 IDs) which correspond to traps that have a fixed geographic location (LAT, LONG). The traps are inspected weekly and with that I get the number of captured insects (femeas). From the month of 06 to 2014 the LAT and LONG columns are empty (`NA`s). I don't know how update the database using the value in the LAT / LONG column in another row of the same ID. Someone can help me?

I tried:

```
ddply(data, "ID", na.locf)
```

but it isn't working.

Part of the data:
https://github.com/daniandreza/spatialtemporal.git

Answer (score 1):

You can use `dplyr::group_by` and `tidyr::fill`:

```
library(dplyr);library(tidyr)
data %>%
   group_by(ID) %>%
   fill(LAT:Y,.direction = "updown")
## A tibble: 41 x 9
## Groups:   ID [3]
#      ID   Dia  Mes    ano FEMEA   LAT  LONG       X        Y
#   <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <dbl> <dbl>   <dbl>    <dbl>
# 1    11    24     4  2014     0 -30.1 -51.2 484034. 6673913.
# 2    11    29     4  2014     1 -30.1 -51.2 484034. 6673913.
# 3    11     7     5  2014     0 -30.1 -51.2 484034. 6673913.
# 4    11     9     1  2014     0 -30.1 -51.2 484034. 6673913.
# 5    11    17     1  2014     1 -30.1 -51.2 484034. 6673913.
# 6    11    21     1  2014     0 -30.1 -51.2 484034. 6673913.
# 7    11    30     1  2014     3 -30.1 -51.2 484034. 6673913.
# 8    11     5     2  2014     0 -30.1 -51.2 484034. 6673913.
# 9    11    13     2  2014     0 -30.1 -51.2 484034. 6673913.
#10    11    21     2  2014     0 -30.1 -51.2 484034. 6673913.
## … with 31 more rows
```

Data

```
data <- data.table::fread("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/daniandreza/spatialtemporal/master/Data_MI.csv",dec = ",")
names(data)[3] <- "Mes"
data.table::setDF(data)
```